# VirtualBox guest: 16 CPUs detected but only 1 online

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, cpu, hot-plug, smp

I am running VirtualBox (using the Qiime image http://qiime.org/install/virtual_box.html)

The physical hardware is a 32 core machine. The virtual machine in VirtualBox has been given 16 cores.

When booting I get:

```
Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS
Linux 2.6.38-15-server

# grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/kernel_max:255
/sys/devices/system/cpu/offline:1-15
/sys/devices/system/cpu/online:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/possible:0-15
/sys/devices/system/cpu/present:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/sched_mc_power_savings:0

# ls /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/per_cpu/
cpu0  cpu1  cpu10  cpu11  cpu12  cpu13  cpu14  cpu15  cpu2  cpu3  cpu4  cpu5  cpu6  cpu7  cpu8  cpu9

# ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/
cpu0  cpufreq  cpuidle  kernel_max  offline  online  possible  present  probe  release  sched_mc_power_savings

# echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/online 
-su: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/online: No such file or directory
```

So it seems it detects the resources for 16 CPUs, but it only sets one online.

I have tested with another image that the VirtualBox host can run a guest with 16 cores. That works. So the problem is to trouble shoot the Qiime image to figure out why this guest image only detects 1 CPU.

Comment: Is it booting an SMP enabled kernel? uname -v should output something like "#1 SMP Thu May 3 14:46:44 UTC 2012"

Comment: Yes. #59~lucid1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 30 23:56:18 UTC 2012

Comment: is IO_APIC enabled ?

Comment: How do I test if IO_APIC is enabled?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

QIIME came out with a new virtualbox image (version 1.5), which works.

If no one finds the answer to the problem above I will close the question in a week.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your VM has been configured to provide a single virtual cpu.

The following documentation might help you in reconfiguring your VM to provide multiple cores:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-processor

This may help, I had a similar issue with an Ubuntu VM.  This help me with my [original question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115807/new-ubuntu-install-only-sees-1-core-of-my-dual-core-cpu)

Comment: As mention in the question I already tried that.